Function of prepositional phrase after to+be
In the following example, I would like to know the function of the emboldened prepositional phrase:

The park is my favorite place to be with my friends.

My first guess is that the prepositional phrase simply functions as an adverb as it modifies the verb to be
However, to be is also a linking verb which could potentially mean that the prepositional phrase is either functioning as a subject complement or adjective.


The park is my favorite place to [be with my friends].

Generally speaking, "be" in an infinitive phrase does not act as a linking verb. The infinitive phrase itself acts as a noun phrase, and no part of a noun phrase can link two other things.
So in this context, "with my friends" is an adverbial (a prepositional phrase, in this case) that modifies "be". The infinitive phrase "to be with my friends" acts like a noun, functioning as a complement to "my favourite place".
You can convince yourself that this is correct by replacing "be" with a more straight-forward verb:

The park is my favourite place to [drink with my friends].

Since the verb "drink" is never a linking verb, we can see that "to be" doesn't link anything either.

Thank you immensely for the clarification.
